# OnClick not firing in UserControl when button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, user-controls

I have a master page.  In the master page I have a UserControl for the footer.  In the footer I have a button that is not firing OnClick.  During debugging I see the function being called by OnClick, btnSignup_Click,  is not getting hit.  I can't seem to figure out where the mistake in my code is.
Also I wanted to note that the validation functionality is working correctly.

master.master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="master" Codebehind="master.master.cs" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="xyz" TagName="Footer" Src="~/controls/footer.ascx" %>


<xyz:Footer ID="Footer" runat="server" />
```

footer.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="footer" Codebehind="footer.ascx.cs"  %>

<div>
     <asp:TextBox ID="fName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorfName"  ValidationGroup="validationSignup" Display="Static" ControlToValidate="fName" ErrorMessage="First Name required" runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>

<div class="button">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSignup"  CommandName="Button" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validationSignup" Text="Signup"  HeaderText="Please fill in all required fields before continuing." OnClick="btnSignup_Click"/>
</div>

<div class="validationSummary">                 
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary"   ValidationGroup="validationSignup" runat="server"></asp:ValidationSummary>
</div>
```

footer.ascx.cs

```
public partial class templates_site_footer : BaseUserControl
{       
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnSignup.Click += new EventHandler(btnSignup_Click);
    }
    protected void btnSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        if (!Page.IsValid)
            return;

        // code to execute after button is clicked
    }
}
```

Comment: did you checked whether the code is hitting the condition in your method or Not (is it hitting `if(!Page.IsValid)`)

Comment: It is not hitting if(!Page.IsValid) during debugging.  The validation works in the sense that the button won't submit if the field is empty.

Comment: try public void btnSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: No luck making the function public.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `btnSignup.Click += new EventHandler(btnSignup_Click);` code from Page_Load event, You had already assigned `OnClick` event to button in .ASCX markup and no need to check validate of your page again in `btnSignup_Click`, you can directly write button click event code which you want to execute.

Your Footer User Control Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //btnSignup.Click += new EventHandler(btnSignup_Click);
}

protected void btnSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
         // code to execute after button is clicked
    }
    else
    {
         // Your page does not validated.
    }
}
```

Comment: During debugging btnSignup_Click() is still not firing.

Comment: Did you make `debug="true"` in web config file?

Comment: Yes, I added breakpoints to Page_Load() and they were getting hit.  I just noticed however that btnSignup.Click += new EventHandler(btnSignup_Click) was not getting hit at its breakpoint

Comment: Did you comment that click event in `btnSignup.Click += new EventHandler(btnSignup_Click)` on page_load event? It does not required.